# How to play more than one video in the same timeline android?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, android-video-player

I want to play video downloaded from Firebase in my android app. Since Firebase does not support live streaming so upload a single video in more than one parts and load one after other for playing. But the segments of video needs to be played continuously in the same timeline so that the user does not get any problem while watching the video. Please help if anyone know it.

Comment: Which `VideoPlayer` you are using in app ? Firebase does not support streaming then why don't use a VideoPlayer which stream the video ?

Comment: I am using exoplayer. How to play videos one after another in the same timeline?

Comment: Well you need queue the next video just after first one finished . Add exo tag with questions and add some more details to get attention .